# display product price with exclusive of tax in magento 2

Tags: magento2, tax, phtml, product-prices

I want to get product price (exclusive of tax) in catalog pages in Magento 2

```
vendor\magento\module-catalog\view\base\templates\product\price\amount\default.phtml
```

I override this file for custom text to my theme.

> I override that file but I want to get the product price (Exclusive
>   of Tax) in Magento 2

how I can do this??

I don't know

Comment: Try this link, https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/tax/display-settings.html

Comment: i want custom text for two prices (Inclu and Exclus ) so that i did customization

Answer (score 0):

There is an admin configuration to display the product prices,

```
Store -> configuration -> Sales -> Price Display Settings -> Display Product Prices In Catalog == Including and Excluding Tax
```